# When I have Check Box checked how to delete row from Table View?

Tags: checkbox, javafx, tableview, tablecolumn

I have these items:

```
@FXML
private Button bttnRemove;
@FXML
private TableView<EventsBean> eventsTable;
@FXML
private TableColumn<EventsBean, String> eventCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<EventsBean, LocalDate> dateCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<EventsBean, Boolean> doneCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<EventsBean, String> observationCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<EventsBean, Boolean> removeCol;
```

and in removeCol I create checkboxes:

```
ObservableList<EventsBean> dataList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

      removeCol.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(removeCol));
      removeCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<EventsBean, Boolean>("remove"));
      eventsTable.setItems(dataList);

      bttnAddEvent.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
        text = eventsSelector.getValue().toString();
        dataList.add(new EventsBean(text, isoDate, ""));
    });

      bttnRemove.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
        //code here...
    });
 }
```

I want to use bttnRemove to delete a row that have checkbox checked from removeCol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find next solution that works very good:

```
public class EventsBean {


private SimpleStringProperty event;
private SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDate> date;
private SimpleStringProperty observation;
private SimpleBooleanProperty selected;

public EventsBean(String event, LocalDate date, String observation, boolean selected) {
    this.event = new SimpleStringProperty(event);
    this.date = new SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDate>(date);
    this.observation = new SimpleStringProperty(observation);
    this.selected = new SimpleBooleanProperty(selected);
}

// the other getters and setters

public boolean getSelected(){
    return selectedProperty().get();
}

public SimpleBooleanProperty selectedProperty() {
    return this.selected;
}
}
```

In my Controller class in initialize method:

```
removeCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().selectedProperty());

bttnRemove.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
        ObservableList<EventsBean> dataListToRemove = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (EventsBean bean : dataList) {
            if (bean.getSelected()) {
                dataListToRemove.add(bean);
            }
        }
        dataList.removeAll(dataListToRemove);
```